# Node.js or Ubuntu Linux run cron on server start up

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, cron

So I have a node server on Ubuntu and I want it to

1. unzip a file that gets uploaded from ftp,
2. read a text file inside, and then
3. save the information to mongodb every day at 4am.

I'm a bit confused on whether I should let ubuntu do that or have my node server do that because I feel like this is a little bit of both: unzipping files to folder is easier with bash and reading and saving to mongodb is easier with javascript (for me).

Any suggestion on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip you can get the file and data from the zip file, then use node to save it.

Though you could also probably use both, use bash to unzip and get the file name then send it as a parameter to the node file and run it, all through bash.